# Nginx to serve only part of a file

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx and need to serve only Nbytes of a file (or seconds/minutes limit of serving). How is it possible to do it with nginx?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you serve the file through a script with php or something. I'm not sure this is possible with Nginx alone.

Comment: Agreed. This is not nginx's responsibility to do that. A script would also grant you better control over the aspects of this.

Comment: +1.  This is the job of a specialized script / application.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself a workaround to use limit_rate , and limit_rate_after, so limit_rate I set to 1, and limit_rate_after the time after which we would like to stop serving the file. The result is that the connection is limited to 1 byte/s after a certain period of time. The bad thing is that the connection is active and there is traffic (even 1 byte/s) and it is not going to time out.
limit_rate              1
limit_rate_after        5m